# Group Theory Questions-Frattini Subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Given a $p$-group $G$ , and its Frattini subgroup $\Phi(G)$ . 
How can one prove the following properties:

1) If $H\triangleleft G$ , then $\Phi(G/H)= \Phi(G)/H$

2) If $G$ is of rank $r$ , and $G/H$ is also of rank $r$ , then $H\leq\Phi(G) $

It is not a homework question, I am just reading a paper and can't understand where do these properties come from

Thanks !

Comment: Can you give a link to the paper if possible?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am pretty sure it should be true in general. If not, then maybe when $G$ is a free pro-$p$ group it should be true... Can you help me ? Thanks !

Comment: The first result is stated incorrectly. You can only write $L/H$ when $H$ is a (normal) subgroup of $L$. I think you should write $\Phi(G/H) = \Phi(G) H / H$ instead.

Comment: The (correct version) of #1 is also a special property of nilpotent groups. Gaschütz defined the prefrattini subgroups for a finite solvable group to have a similar property (and so that the Frattini subgroup in any quotient was the normal core of their image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both results, you should use the fact that for a subgroup $K$ of $G$, the following are equivalent

- $\Phi(G) \le K$, and
- $K$ is normal in $G$, and $G/K$ is elementary abelian.

> And note that the correct form of (1) is $\Phi(G/H) = \Phi(G) H / H$, as I wrote in the comment to OP.

So for (1) write $\Phi(G/H) = K/H$. Then $$(G/H)/\Phi(G/H) = (G/H)/(K/H) \cong G/K$$ is elementary abelian, so that $\Phi(G) \le K$. Now $H \le \Phi(G) H \le K$, and 
$$
\left(\frac{G}{H}\right) \Big/\left(\frac{\Phi(G) H}{H}\right) \cong \frac{G}{\Phi(G) H} \cong \left(\frac{G}{\Phi(G)}\right)\Big/\left(\frac{\Phi(G) H}{\Phi(G)}\right)
$$
is elementary abelian, as a quotient of $G/\Phi(G)$, so that $\Phi(G/H) = K/H \le \Phi(G) H/H$, that is, $K \le \Phi(G) H$, and thus $K = \Phi(G) H$.

For (2), use (1) to obtain that
$$
\frac{G}{\Phi(G)}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{G}{\Phi(G) H}
$$
have the same order $p^{r}$. Since $\Phi(G) \le \Phi(G) H$, we have $\Phi(G) = \Phi(G) H$, or $H \le \Phi(G)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndreasCaranti ! 
Just to clarify one last thing:
In case where $H \subseteq \Phi(G) $ , it is obviously legitimate to write $\Phi(G/H) = \Phi(G)/H $ right? 

Thanks!

Comment: @czash, you're welcome! Of course, yes, as I said, when the subgroup $L$ contains the normal subgroup $H$, then one can write $L/H$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti can you give me a reference of this equivalence that you mentioned at the begin of the proof? Thanks a lot

Comment: @RodolfoFerreiradeOliveira I do not have access to the library just now, but you can deduce the characterization from the following standard facts. First of all for a subgroup $K$ the following are equivalent: (1) $G' \le K$ (2) $K$ is normal in $G$, and $G/K$ is abelian. And then, in a finite $p$-group $\Phi(G) = G' Gˆ{p} $, where $Gˆ{p} $ is the subgroup generated by the $p$-th powers.

Answer (score 3):

Hint for the first one:

We know that if $K$ is normal subgroup in group $G$ so every subgroup of $G/K$ can be written as $H/K$ wherein $K\le H\le G$. This helps us to see that every maximal subgroups of $G/K$ has a form like $$H/K,~~~~K\le H\le G,~~~\text{and}~H~~\text{is maximal in}~~G$$. And obviously If $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ including $K$, so $H/K$ is maximal in $G/K$. Now consider the definition of $\Phi(G)$ and take $K\le\Phi (G)$ and make an conclusion in which the first claim is true.

Comment: @czash: Welcome :-)

Comment: This is probably wrong. You have shown that $\Phi(G/K) \geq \Phi(G)K/K$ for an arbitrary finite group. However, equality is false in general, for instance AGL(1,9) has trivial Frattini, but if you mod out by the Fitting, you get cyclic of order 8, which has Frattini of order 4.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Thanks Jack. I did it according to Lemma 11.8 of A Course on G.T. by J.S.Rose.

Comment: Ah, I see. You interpreted the original question here as assuming $K \leq \Phi(G)$ which is sufficient (and is Lemma 11.8.2). For $p$-groups, you don't have to assume $K \leq \Phi(G)$, but that is special for $p$-groups.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Thank you my Prof.

Answer (score 2):

Hint for the second one: the rank of $G$ is defined as the rank of $G/\Phi(G)$. Using the first one and an isomorphism theorem $(G/H)/\Phi(G/H) = (G/H)/(\Phi(G)/H) \simeq G/\Phi(G)$ and you are done.

Comment: Great ! Thanks !